# multiplicação de matrizes com minimo maximo de cada linha

Tags: c

olá eu fiz um programa com o intuito de multiplicar cada elemento de cada linha de uma matriz pelo seu elemento de valo mais alto, mas meu programa multiplica cada um por ele mesmo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

//achar maior menor de cada linha da matriz e e multiplicar cada numero da linha por ele
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int mat[4][4];
    int i, j, aux;

    //le matriz
    for(i=0; i<=3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=3; j++)
        {
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
            printf("digite um numero para a posição %d e coluna %d de mat:\n", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //1ºfase de processamento
    for(i=0; i<=3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=3; j++)
        {
        if(mat[i][j]>mat[i][j] || mat[i][j]==mat[i][j] )//se o elemento na posição mat={i,j} for o maior numero da linha
            {
                aux=mat[i][j];//guardar em aux
                mat[i][j]=mat[i][j]*aux;
            }
        }
    }

    system("cls");
    fflush(stdin);

    for(i=0; i<=3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=3; j++)
        {
            printf("[%d]", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Olá Leonardo, dei uma lida em algumas de suas questões anteriores e tive a impressão de que você está tentando resolver uma série de exercícios com C em ambiente Windows (me corrija se estiver errado). Só gostaria de deixar um comentário: Já descobriu como usar o [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)? O *debugger* pode vir a te ajudar bastante. Além do mais, a maioria dos IDES (incluindo o Dev-C++ que professores de faculdade gostam de recomendar) suportam GDB.

Comment: sim uso windows, obrigado @AnthonyAccioly eu to no 2 período de ciências da computação eu tiro as duvidas aqui por que o pessoal respondem e os professores da faculdade não irei procurar o GDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma função auxiliar para calcular o maior elemento de um vetor:

```
int maxElement(int array[], int arraySize)
{
    int max = array[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > max)
            max = array[i];
    }

    return max;
}
```

Então adapte sua lógica para utilizar essa função:

```
//1º fase de processamento
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    // Calcula o valor do maior elemento da linha
    int aux = maxElement(mat[i], 4);
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        // Mesma coisa do que mat[i][j] = mat[i][j] * aux
        mat[i][j] *= aux;      
    }
}
```

---

#### [Exemplo funcional no Ideone](http://ideone.com/gsksbG)

Comment: ainda não intendi eu nao gostaria de usar função mesmo ja conhecendo pois a professora vai reclamar e pedir para eu explciar função e não estou afiado nesse assunto aidna eu nao intendi o seu algoritmo o meu nao esta tao longe assim ele so multiplica ou cada numero por ele mesmo ou somente o maior numero de cada linha meu ultimo algoritmo

Comment: ` //fase de processamento
 for(i=0; i<=3; i++)
 {
  for(j=0; j<=3; j++)
  {

   if(mat[i][j]>=mat[i][3])//se o elemento na posição mat={i,j} 
   {           //for maior que o ultimo elemento da linha

    aux=mat[i][j];//guardar em aux
    mat[i][j]=aux*mat[i][j];//multiplica aux por cada numero da linha
   }
   
  }
 }`

Comment: Olá Leonardo. A definição do algoritmo é: Para cada linha (laço externo), encontre o maior elemento da linha (função auxiliar) e multiplique-o por cada elemento da linha (laço interno). O seu algoritmo está pulando o passo de calcular o maior elemento da linha e está fazendo um `if` desnecessário. Recomendo que você passe um tempo debbugando essa solução no GDB caso algo não tenha ficado claro. Caso queira transformar tudo em uma única função, transportar o corpo da função `maxElement` para dentro do laço externo é trivial, porém eu não faria isso (dessa maneira fica bem mais limpo).

Comment: // Calcula o valor do maior elemento da linha
    int aux = maxElement(mat[i], 4);
por que o `,4`

Comment: É o tamanho do array. Uma matriz é um array de arrays. Sua matriz é um array de 4 linhas, onde cada linha é um array de 4 posições (logo `int [4][4]`). O `4` é passado como argumento (parâmetro `int arraySize`). Em C é prática comum passar o tamanho do vetor junto com ele.